# How can I retrieve data in Arrow format when querying Snowflake in Java

Tags: java, jdbc, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, apache-arrow

I know that the [Snowflake JDBC](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/jdbc.html#) library is [using Apache Arrow](https://www.snowflake.com/blog/fetching-query-results-from-snowflake-just-got-a-lot-faster-with-apache-arrow/?lang=fr) to transfer query results.

However, the only API I can find in the library is iterating row by row on my result set:

```java
ResultSet resultSet = connection.createStatement().executeQuery(query);
while (resultSet.next()) {
    // Do something
}
```

How can I directly retrieve the Arrow vectors ?

Comment: Wondering: What's the overall goal?

Comment: I want to pass it to a library expecting a columnar format and I don't want this extra layer of conversion to rows. And I can see other use cases such as saving a result on disk fast or sending the result to another process.

Comment: Wondering: Which library? What interface is it expecting?

Comment: I think Arrow is used internally by the JDBC driver rather than something made available by the API.

Comment: This has been raised as a feature request in the snowflake jdbc project: https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-jdbc/issues/1422

For anyone looking for this functionality go +1 this :)

Answer (score 1):

By default nowadays the JDBC query result format is ARROW, and this can be verified in the account by doing:

```
show parameters like 'JDBC_QUERY_RESULT_FORMAT';
```

If for any reason it was set to JSON you can also set it to ARROW at session level:

```
alter session set JDBC_QUERY_RESULT_FORMAT='ARROW'
```

Comment: I know it is using it internally, but how can I access the Arrow vecotrs to use them directly ?

Comment: I see what you mean now, it's not possible as far as I see in JDBC code.